LSP mode connecting to wrong server
I'm trying to read the postgres source code. My lsp server connects to the clangd lsp for some reason even though the project is using C.
[-] /home/jenia/git/postgresql
 `-[-] clangd:40775
    |-[-] Buffers
    |  `-[+] dblink.c
    `-[+] Capabilities
[X] /usr/include/postgresql

I can't find a way to change the lsp server lsp-mode is connecting to. Can someone please give me a hint?
Thanks kindly in advance.

I simply installed https://github.com/emacs-lsp/emacs-ccls :)
